# Errors after updating Ionic 2 : main.ts was not found

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have updated my Ionic 2 and given ionic serve to my project, but am getting these errors:

[image: ionic error after project update]

How do I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, when you update something i recommend you to read changelogs.

Btw here is your answer, in ionic [2.0.0 RC4](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc4-2016-12-15) you needed to update into ionic app scripts 0.0.47 but this version got some breaking changes.

> Entry Point Changes
>
> Delete main.dev.ts and main.prod.ts and create a main.ts file with the
>   following content:
>
> import { platformBrowserDynamic } from
>   '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
>
> import { AppModule } from './app.module';
>
> platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

This changes are in the [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0047-2016-12-12).

With this changes you will solve your problem.

Comment: okbut my version is ionic framework is 2.0.0-rc.6 and ionic cli version 2.2.1

Comment: no matters do that change cause that change affects to RC4, RC5, RC6, final..... and ionic app scripts 0.0.47, 0.0.48, 1.0.0, 1.1.0... changes in one RC affects to others.